# TypeScript node sample won't compile

Tags: typescript, tsc

It seems everyone's got the sample to work, but mine just won't...

I have nodejs 0.8.2 install in windows 7 64bit. Did a `npm install -g typescript` to get TypeScript support. Then I downloaded the source from TypeScript and tried the samples
but I just can't get the node sample to compile. It returns the error message:

```
c:\..\..\typescript\bin\tsc.js:21182
           if(_fs.existsSync(path)) {
                  ^
TypeError: Object #(Object) has no method 'existsSync'
...
...
```

Has anyone else seen this problem?

Been looking around for hours without finding anything.

Say that I have this code:

```
///<reference path="node.d.ts"/>


import http = module("http");

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res)
{
    res.writeHead(200, { 'ContenType': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(1337);
```

Typed this up in Visual 2012 express for web, which showed no error. The reference is in place, and intellisense is working fine. But when I use the command-line tool with node to compile this file, it pops the error shown further up.. I did not include _fs.existsSync in my own code.

Ok... after playing around with tsc.js and nodejs... I realized that the _fs object created from require('fs') in node engine doesn't have a function called existsSync at all...

After searching a bit more... apparently this function is now under the path module...
I'll try editing tsc.js to use the path module's existsSync function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... change the tsc.js to use _path.existsSync instead seem to work.
But after some more fiddling around,  I found the the node version on my system is still v0.6.2.
Even though I tried to install v0.8.12 downloaded from the site before.
After removing v0.6.2 and installed v0.8.14, now the fs module contains the target function.

I wonder why the node version on this system was stuck on 0.6.2 ~''~

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because you a have a typo error in your code. Try using `fs.existsSync(path)`. You are trying to assign a method to an object which does not exists.

```
fs.existsSync('path/to/file');
```

or 
`fs.exists()` which is synonymous with the above, only you are using a callback if connection has succeeded.

```
fs.exists('/path/to/file', function (exists) {
  util.debug(exists ? "it's there" : "no passwd!");
});
```

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback

Comment: hmmm... but that is not my code... it's the sample given in the typescript source files downloaded from codeplex...

Comment: have you seen the examples in the node samples from typescript?
like... while referencing node.d.ts, if i have just import http = module("http"); in the code, the compile would fail

Comment: found the problem... it's because somehow the node version on this system wasn't updated to 0.8.xx when I tried to install with the installer from nodejs.org. It was stuck with version 0.6.2, possibly because it was 32 bit version, and I tried to update it with a 64 bit installer. Thanks for the help anyways.